# Formatting data with three colors

Tags: excel, vba

I generate random data in an Excel table within a certain range, with some random generated abnormal values (this part is working).

I want to give these values colors, green for normal values, yellow for abnormal and red for over the limits.

I tested this method with last column, representing pH because looking at the values it's easy to tell which one are good or bad without use of colors.

I used an if/else if condition to format values by colors. Red values are fine because it is a fixed value in the code, but yellow and green are messed up as it is either all green or all yellow with all the things I tried.

My whole code.

```
Sub TAB1()
    'Déclaration
    Dim Tableau(95, 5)

    Dim r1, r2, r3, r4 As Double 'random variables
    
    Dim vNH4g, vNH4y, vNH4r, vNKg, vNKy, vNKr, vNGg, vNGy, vNGr, vpHg, vpHy, vpHr As Double
    'v for value, g for green (0<v<80% of max value or +/-5%), y for yellow (80<v<99 or +/- 5<v<10%), r for red (100% and +)

    Dim NH4fv, NKfv, NGfv, pHfv As Double
    'fv for final value

    Randomize

    'Enregistrement des valeurs dans le tableau
    For i = 0 To 95
        'Variables randoms
        r1 = Rnd * 100 + 1
        r2 = Rnd * 100 + 1
        r3 = Rnd * 100 + 1
        r4 = Rnd * 100 + 1
        
        'Variables pour remplir tableau
        vNH4g = Int((10.5 - 4.75) * Rnd + 4.75)
        vNH4y = Int((11 - 4.5) * Rnd + 4.5)
        vNH4r = Int((11 - 4.5) * Rnd + 11)
        
        vNKg = Int((12.6 - 6.65) * Rnd + 6.65)
        vNKy = Int((13.2 - 6.3) * Rnd + 6.3)
        vNKr = Int((13.2 - 6.3) * Rnd + 13.2)
        
        vNGg = Int((57.75 - 52.25) * Rnd + 52.25)
        vNGy = Int((60.5 - 49.5) * Rnd + 49.5)
        vNGr = Int((60.5 - 49.5) * Rnd + 60.5)
        
        vpHg = ((6.7 - 6.2) * Rnd + 6.2)
        vpHy = ((7.37 - 5.58) * Rnd + 5.58)
        vpHr = 8.5
        
        
        'Heure
        Tableau(i, 0) = Range("A" & i + 2)
        
        
        'N-NH4+
        If r3 < 80 Then Range("B" & i + 2) = vNH4g
        If 80 < r3 < 90 Then Range("B" & i + 2) = vNH4y
        If 90 < r3 Then Range("B" & i + 2) = vNH4r
        
        Tableau(i, 1) = Range("B" & i + 2)
        
        
        'NK
        If r3 < 80 Then Range("C" & i + 2) = vNKg
        If 80 < r3 < 90 Then Range("C" & i + 2) = vNKy
        If 90 < r3 Then Range("C" & i + 2) = vNKr
                            
        Tableau(i, 2) = Range("C" & i + 2)
        
        
        'NG
        If r3 < 80 Then Range("D" & i + 2) = vNGg
        If 80 < r3 < 90 Then Range("D" & i + 2) = vNGy
        If 90 < r3 Then Range("D" & i + 2) = vNGr
        
        Tableau(i, 3) = Range("D" & i + 2)
        
        
        'pH  
        If r4 <= 80 Then Range("E" & i + 2) = vpHg
        If 80 < r4 <= 90 Then Range("E" & i + 2) = vpHy
        If r4 > 90 Then Range("E" & i + 2) = vpHr
        
        Tableau(i, 4) = Range("E" & i + 2)
        
        pHfv = Range("E" & i + 2)
                                
        If pHfv = vpHr Then Range("E" & i + 2).Interior.Color = vbRed Else If vpHy <= pHfv < vpHy Then Range("E" & i + 2).Interior.Color = vbYellow Else If vpHg <= pHfv < vpHg Then Range("E" & i + 2).Interior.Color = vbGreen      
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It's quite hard to tell from that what exactly is the problem. Can't you use conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not recommend using if on a single line, it limits the writing of the (and) in the if, use structural, it is better to understand and write, if you want then try to put a single line, without the end if.
I don't know if how I put the criteria is correct! check you!
Try this way.

```
 If pHfv = vpHr Then
            range("E" & i + 2).Interior.Color = vbRed
        Else
            If (pHfv <= vpHy) And (pHfv > vpHg) Then
                range("E" & i + 2).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        Else
            If (pHfv < vpHg) Then
                range("E" & i + 2).Interior.Color = vbGreen
            End If
        End If
        End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your explaination, it works as intended and working with multiples lines is much clearer that what I had done ! Have a great day thanks